# Mandatory Embedded schema field not throwing exception when empty in SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, schema

I am pulling back to the basic schema questions in Tridion 2011. 
I have an embedded schema with three optional fields. 
I referred this embedded schema in a content schema and marked it(parent field) as mandatory. 
When I create a component and save it without entering data to this mandatory field; CME is not throwing any exception and proceeds with saving.

Please let me know if there are any patches to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hotfix for this issue because it's working as intended.

Tridion checks the fields one by one if there require a value (mandatory) since they are optional its saves without a problem.

I guess you can try and resolve it by writing a custom event; have a look at this blog post of Robert Curlette http://www.curlette.com/?p=90

Comment: Yes, i am planning to implement custom event.  Thanks all for all your inputs.

Comment: This might help: http://nunolinhares.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html

Answer (score 3):

It helps if you think about the underlying XSD. Making the Embedded Schema mandatory simply means that the (root) element is required -- it says nothing about the elements inside. So this is working as intended: the GUI will add the element without any user interaction. There is no option to say "I need the user to fill in these optional fields" - since that doesn't really make any sense.

If you need the user to fill in those fields, you'll need to make one or more of the embedded fields mandatory as well.

Answer (score 1):

what exact version of Tridion are you using (2011 SP1, 2011 SP1 HR1, 2011 SP1 HR2)?

Are any of the embedded fields mandatory?  One possible solution is to make those fields mandatory as well.

You can check for public hotfixes on www.sdltridionworld.com (login required), under Downloads - Hotfixes -

Comment: I am working on Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2.  I cannot make embedded fields mandatory since they are referred in other content schema's too; requirement requires them to be mandatory for this specific schema.